# div tags - float attribute

Tags: html, runatserver

I am new to div tags since I was using tables previously. I would like to display label and text box eg: First Name :***_*__*_*__*_*_** for that I have written like this

```
<div>
<div>firstName</div><div style="float:left;"><asp:textbox id="test" runat="server"/></div></div>.
```

I guess creates one section, right ? I don't get how float attribute takes textbox control to the first line instead of second line. pls clarify !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign both label and the input field an ID and set then both to float:left.

like:

```
<label id="testLabel" for="input1">Name:</label>
```

or if you have them placed in separate divs, then assign those divs an ID and float them.

Comment: in the same code, if we don't give float:left ...it shows in two lines. I didn't get how float:left makes this.

Comment: you have a syntax error in your div tag definition, it should be <div style="float:left;">firstname</div>. this should work, although I wouldn't recommend inline style, just assign this div an ID and set the float in your CSS file.

Comment: correct code:<div>
        <div>RTO Office</div>
        <div style="float:left;"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="formRTO"></asp:TextBox>       </div>
      </div>

Comment: why do you need so many divs? you can use label tag for your label text, if it puts them in two lines, just assign your label an ID and float it as well. hope this helps :)